# Remove anchor tags around text in content

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove anchor tags around the text of content but need to keep if it is with specific URL's :

```
this is example text <a href="www.1.com">hello</a> and
this is second link <a href="www.2.com">hello word two</a>
this is third link <a href="www.3.com">hello word three</a>
this is fourth link <a href="www.4.com">hello word four</a>
```

I only want to remove anchors with href's from www.1.com and www.2.com and want to keep other.
Currently I am using following code which is removing all the anchor tags :

```
preg_replace( '/<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/i','\1', $content )
```

Please help.

Comment: Try :




    `preg_replace( '/<a href="www\.(?:1|2)\.com">([^<]+)<\/a>/i','\1', $content )`

Comment: its not working. but I will not be having actual url's in real scenario.. I will only have that url's which I do not want to remove..   I will be having 3.com and 4.com only rest all I want to remove. that way pls help

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace instead
for replace your anchor tag with blank
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

or

$str = 'www.1.com';
echo trim(preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', ' ', $str));

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but url's will not be predefined.. I will just have those url's which I do not want to omit rest all I need to omit from text.

Answer (score 0):

As is widely known, regex is not the safest tool to manipulate HTML.

I suggest parsing the string with `DOMDocument`, find all `a` tags whose `href` attribute value contains `www.1.com` or `www.2.com` and remove only them:

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body>TEXTthis is example text <a href=\"www.1.com\">hello</a> and
this is second link <a href=\"www.2.com\">hello word two</a>
this is third link <a href=\"www.3.com\">hello word three</a>
this is fourth link <a href=\"www.4.com\">hello word four</a></body></html>"; 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//a[contains(@href,"www.1.com") or contains(@href,"www.2.com")]');
foreach ($links as $link) {
       $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See this [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/nShgLp)

A regex should only be considered as a means of last resort, especially when you cannot fix corrupt HTML. In that case, a fallback solution can be a [`'~<a\s[^<]*?\bhref="www\.[12]\.com"[^<]*?>[^<]*<\/a>~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/kY2iA6/1) regex that matches `a` tags that have `href` values equal to `www.1.com` or `www.2.com`. Or [`'~<a\s[^<]*?\bhref="[^<"]*?www\.[12]\.com[^<]*?>[^<]*<\/a>~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/kY2iA6/2) if the hrefs can *contain* those domain names.